# STM32 RTC3 Mixed Mode: Writing TR resets SSR

Tags: arm, embedded, stm32, real-time-clock

Some of the new STM32 chips include a binary RTC mode, which, for example, is used for the LoRaWAN stack timing in the examples.
The RTC can be run in mixed mode, where both binary part (32-bit down-counting sub-seconds register SSR) and classic BCD calender mode are operational.

This works perfectly fine until I try to set the BCD calender time part with HAL_RTC_SetTime.

It turned out, that as soon as RTC->TR is written, RTC->SSR is reset to 0xFFFFFFFF.
As all timers backed by the binary mode rely on SSR, they fail.

I tried backing up SSR and writing back after RTC->TR write, but it seems to be read-only.

Am I missing something? If a mixed mode has been introduced, I doubt normal behaviour is that the BCD part cannot be set anymore without affecting the binary mode part.

Comment: DId you check the errata? Last time I worked with RTC it has been very helpful for me.

Comment: Interesting document, did not know. But there's nothing in on this topic...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this seems to be by design. After RTC init mode exits, SSR is reset:

https://community.st.com/t5/stm32-mcus-products/stm32-rtc3-mixed-mode-writing-tr-resets-ssr/m-p/655899/highlight/true#M239486